# How to update FETCH and PUSH with another GitHub URL

Tags: git

Not sure what happened, but my client_meta repo is pointing to another repo.

When I do a

```
git remote -v
```

I see the following:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after some time.

I had a redundant origin entry in my `~/.gitconfig` file.  I simply edited the file and deleted the line.  Works fine now.

Hopefully may help someone.